# Using Win32_Computersystem with Win32_service on same line and output-csv

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, wmi

I am using Get-WmiObject Win32_service and piping the output to CSV.
My script is collecting services running, but I would like to display osname, ip and domain for the object on the same line in my csv (so I can easily sort with Excel).

Is there a way I can combine the two?

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem
Get-WmiObject Win32_service
```

Or maybe I could sneak in some variables from my Get-QADComputer into this line:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_service -Computername $server.name -Filter "State='Running'" | select -Property SystemName,Name,Status,State,Startmode,DisplayName | Export-Csv -Append -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Path $reportfile
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `New-Object` cmdlet to create new object for each service object and add the properties you want (osname) from the `Win32_OperatingSystem` WMI class (os caption is not avaiable in the `Win32_ComputerSystem` class).

```
$ComputerName = 'PC1'

$os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName

Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $ComputerName -Filter "State='Running'" | Foreach-Object{

    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        SystemName=$_.SystemName
        Name=$_.Name
        Status=$_.Status
        State=$_.State
        StartMode=$_.Startmode
        DisplayName=$_.DisplayName
        IPAddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($_.SystemName)[0].IPAddressToString
        OSName = $os.Caption            
    } | Select-Object SystemName,Name,Status,State,StartMode,DisplayName,IPAddress,OSName

} | Export-Csv -Append -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Path $reportfile
```

Comment: Thank you very much Shay! I didn't know about New-Object.

Comment: Thank you very much Shay! I didn't know about New-Object. But.. IPAddress is only returning System.Net.IPAddress[] and $os.caption is returning Microsoft? Windows Server? 2008 Standard. How can I simply get the IP Address and a proper formatted os version name? Merry christmas by the way!!

Comment: Yes, it returns an array of addresses. I updated  the code so you can get the first address.

Comment: Thank you ever so much:) Wouldn't WMI query for the IP address everytime it loops through a server this way? Shouldn't I put the IP address query outside the foreach loop?   (it's bit of a pain that I get no notification of people responding to my posts.. I have to manually go in here and check.. Is this normal?)

Comment: The IP query should be inside the the loop cause each iteration you query another name. As for notification, it sucks, that's the only info I have http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/now-showing-email-notifications/.